# Razor redirect contains unexpected behaviors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a very simple login page. The issue is is in the Login method. I execute RedirectToAction, however, it never changes the webpage from the login page to the home page.

HomeController (main application controller)

```
    public ActionResult Index(string username = null, string password = null)
    {
        if (username == null || password == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Auth");
        }

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        return View(); //and have tried return View("Index");
    }
```

AuthController (grabs the username and password)

```
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {           
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home", new { username=username,password=password});
    }
```

Button Press

```
function Login() {
    var _get_searchdetails = '@Url.Action("Login", "Auth")';
    $.ajax({
    url: _get_searchdetails,
    data: { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val() },
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert("Try again!");
    },
    success: function (htmldata, xhr, settings) {

    }
    });
}
```

Comment: `type: "GET",` *\* GASP* *

Comment: Setting fields on the controller isn't going to work, as the controller is instantiated and disposed with each request. The next request you make, `username` and `password` will be null again.

Comment: Yes, I save those... 
Session["username"] = login.username;  AND Session["password"] = login.password; Thank you though!

Comment: You should also decorate the `Login` method with the `[HttpPost]` attribute and probably `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` too (assuming you also put `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the form).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, my primary concern was to get something working since it is an internal application which will be protected by certificates.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not clear what you are trying to do here, as you action method code does not makes sense.

But the better option here can be to use [`RedirecToAction` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) by specifying the controller and action name with the parameters of it like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home", new { username=username,password=password});
```

and you should not be using `Get` request for passing username and password to action method, as it is very vulnerable to hackers to hack in to the web application easily.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Made a few updates. I am attempting to do a simple login page to grab the users credentials to impersonate downstream. The problem is once RedirectToAction as you had mentioned is executed, it remains at the login view.

Answer (score 0):

Found my Problem. I needed to do this instead of an ajax query.

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Auth"))
        {
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
            <br />
            <label for="username">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        }
```

Comment: If you wanted to keep the ajax behaviour you could return a url in the response and have the browser redirect to that url from javascript (something like `location = response.url`). But in general, it is unnecessary to `POST` using ajax in this sort of scenario.

Comment: Nope, I really had no need for the ajax. I just did not know exactly what I was searching for to get it to work. I have never used Razor 5 before and I was trying to write code and learn it at the same time which does not always work out well.